# Is it a good idea to make mysql connections static?

Tags: php, mysql, static-variables

I'm working on a medium-sized (probably) PHP system which had MySQL connections being opened everywhere throughout different files and, made into global variables for the later included scripts to have access to. Since I'm creating another module, I'd like to avoid globals and keeping the same mysql connection for each page request. My current solution is this:

```
Class Db {
        static public $dbConnectionArray = array();
}
```

For every request, the connections would be saved in the static array and referred back to at a later time. What do you think could go wrong? And why?

Would like to hear some opinions on how to best tackle this as I would love to reduce the number of opened connections per script run (currently, one page request invoked about 6-15 mysql connections to at least 3 different databases).

Comment: if you create a class that handles all your db interaction then you will not have to worry about this

Comment: Why do you have more than 1 connection to a single database?

Comment: @prodigitalson: I haven't looked deeply into the process but I suspect that the global connections get re-initialized half-way through the script run. While I profiled the code, I spotted mysql_connect() being called several times for certain function calls which involve including a .php file which included another one, and so on...

Comment: Hmmm... its been a **long** time since ive used the `mysql` extension in production (i use PDO exclusively now), but i thought it was "smart" and grabbed the already open connection if the signature matched.

Comment: @prodigitalson: yep, by default that would be the case but our code specified the new_link flag in order to establish a fresh connection everytime.

Comment: @fred: what was your resoning behind doing that? Arent you seentially undoing it with what you want to implement? And if so wouldnt it just be easier to remove the flags?

Comment: @prodigitalson: it was done by the chief engineer so it would take time for me to inquire and justify and wait for approval (or rejection), even for minute details. I'm just trying to see if there is a workaround since this is the one thing that cannot be so easily modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to reinvent the wheel. you can use mysql persistent connections to keep connections alive. (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php)

By using persistent connections, your PHP scripts will reuse the same database connections (as long as the database name & credentials are the same)

Also, if your databases are on the same host, you should be able to use the same mysql connection by using `mysql_select_db()` function.

Comment: OTOH, persistent connections are discouraged in MySQL, because the connection process is quite cheap - on one side - and it can induce the one or other problem, like forgotten table locks etc.

Comment: Using persistent connections would require re-writing the whole mysql class library which we are currently using. It's tightly coupled to all database operations, thus developers cannot touch it without HOD's approval. Best I can do is write some wrapper class to alleviate the current issues.